# How to read a group of csv files with diffrent seperation?

Tags: r, csv

How we can read a group of .csv file which they have different separation such as "," or ";" in correct form( True number of column)?
I have tried this code:

```
dat <-read.csv(file = dataset, header = TRUE, sep = c(",",";"))
```

but all my column insert to one column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have to read your csv file as is, and then in R separate them into columns. Once loaded, you can use `stringr` package, e.g. [`str_split`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stringr/versions/1.4.0/topics/str_split) to split up each row into several columns, or `tidyr`'s [`separate`](https://rawgit.com/rstudio/cheatsheets/master/data-import.pdf).